# issue returning CArray

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, compiler-errors

I am trying to return a `CArray` from a function and trying to call the function from another class

```
short ListMaker::RetArray(CString szName, CArray<CString, CString&> &szarr_Names) {
    szarr_Names.Add(szName);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main() {
    //..
    CArray<CString, CString&> myArray;
    ListMaker LM;
    short nCode = LM.RetArray(L"Name", myArray);
    //..
}
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'RetArray' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>' to 'CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>'
Error   2   error C2511: 'short RetArray(CString,CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'ListMaker'
```

Please tell me the correct way to define and access the return value of the CArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, frist of all if `RetArray` is a member of `ListMaker` class and you call it from `main()`, you cannot call it like this: `short nCode = RetArray(L"Name", myArray);`

If `RetArray` is a static member, use `short nCode = ListMaker::RetArray(L"Name", myArray);`. It it's non-static, use instance, `short nCode = listMakerInstance.RetArray(L"Name", myArray);`.

Check your header file for `RetArray` declaration in `ListMaker` class. It might differ from the implementation in your cpp file, hence you get the C2511 error.

Comment: yes, I have modified as you have suggested, but I am still getting the same error. Just tell me how to return and call CArray properly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store a reference in an array type, and CArray is to be absolutely avoided at all costs as it uses memcpy to resize and not copy construction, breaking your code the instant you need something with a useful constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `CString&`, try using `CArray<CString, LPCTSTR>` instead.